# Doesn't find ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I made an ArrayList to populate the CustomAdapter. Everything works so far but the text of the ArrayList doesn't appear. Even the buttons update the text of the numbers on the click. If I put a breakpoint in the ArrayList it does not break there, so the whole ArrayList is not found. Why, and if it is declared in the wrong place, where should I put it.

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public static ArrayList<Model> brandlist;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private Button btnnext;
//public static ArrayList brandlist;

public static void onCreate(String[] args) {

    ArrayList brandlist = new ArrayList<>();

        brandlist.add("340ml NRB (85023)");
        brandlist.add("330ml Cans (85736)");
        brandlist.add("500ml Cans (85024)");
        brandlist.add("440ml NRB (86798)");
        brandlist.add("330ml RB (85556)");
        brandlist.add("750ml RB (85021)");
        brandlist.add("340ml NRB 12 pack (87009)");
        brandlist.add("500ml Cans 12 Pack (85022)");
  }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    btnnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

    brandlist = getModel();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager     (getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<Model> getModel(){
    ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setNumber(0);
        model.setBrandlist(brandlist);
        list.add(model);
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

And here is the CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context ctx;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) MainActivity.brandlist.get(position).getBrandlist());
    holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(MainActivity.brandlist.get(position).getNumber()));
    holder.tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(MainActivity.brandlist.get(position).getNumber()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return MainActivity.brandlist.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected Button btn_cases_plus, btn_cases_minus, btn_pallets_plus, btn_pallets_minus;
    private TextView tvBrand, tvCases,tvPallets;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvBrand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
        tvCases = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
        tvPallets = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
        btn_cases_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.casePlus1);
        btn_cases_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caseMinus1);
        btn_pallets_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.palletsPlus1);
        btn_pallets_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.palletsMinus1);

        btn_cases_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_cases_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_cases_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_cases_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_cases_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_cases_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pallets_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_pallets_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_pallets_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pallets_minus.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // onClick Listener for view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == btn_cases_plus.getId()){

            View tempview = (View) btn_cases_plus.getTag(R.integer.btn_cases_plus_view);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString()) + 1;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            MainActivity.brandlist.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(number);

        } else if(v.getId() == btn_cases_minus.getId()) {

            View tempview = (View) btn_cases_minus.getTag(R.integer.btn_cases_minus_view);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString()) - 1;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            MainActivity.brandlist.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(number);
        }
    }

}
}
```

And here is the Model file:

```
public class Model {

private int number;
private ArrayList brandlist;

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public ArrayList getBrandlist() {
    return brandlist;
}

public void setBrandlist(ArrayList brandlist) {
    this.brandlist = brandlist;
}

public ArrayList getbrandlist() {
    return brandlist;
}
}
```

Comment: There are two references of brandlist one is in onCreate and another outside of it, you are populating one but using other, second thing pass array list to your adapter from constuctor instead

Comment: Guys, is it possible to cast ArrayList to CharSeqence? Or maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Even if I move it to my Model class it doesn't work. Why does it tell my my onCreate method is never uses.

Comment: Another nice newbie question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a very confusing setup here that is likely to lead to problems down the road. That being said...

First, this method doesn't do anything:

```
public static void onCreate(String[] args) {
    ArrayList brandlist = new ArrayList<>();
    brandlist.add("340ml NRB (85023)");
    brandlist.add("330ml Cans (85736)");
    brandlist.add("500ml Cans (85024)");
    brandlist.add("440ml NRB (86798)");
    brandlist.add("330ml RB (85556)");
    brandlist.add("750ml RB (85021)");
    brandlist.add("340ml NRB 12 pack (87009)");
    brandlist.add("500ml Cans 12 Pack (85022)");
}
```

There's no lifecycle method with this signature, so unless you're calling it manually, it will never be invoked. It looks like you copied a non-Android program's `main()` method and changed the name to `onCreate()`.

Even if you do manually invoke this method, it won't do anything. The first line (`ArrayList brandlist = ...`) is creating a list and assigning it to a local variable. It is **not** initializing your `MainActivity.brandlist`.

In your *real* `onCreate()` method (the second one), you initialize `MainActivity.brandlist` with the results of the `getModel()` call. At the time you call this method, `MainActivity.brandlist` is null, so you are essentially building up a list of eight items all with `number` = 0 and `brandlist` = null.

From there you create your adapter etc, which all looks fine.

I recommend taking a step back and thinking about what you're trying to accomplish. Probably you will eventually wind up re-writing the majority of this code. Perhaps a colleague or a teacher could help with this.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I did just that and went back to when it was last working. At that stage it was a string that populated the text filed, and trouble started when I wanted to change it to an ArrayList. I wrote most of the MainActivity over and now its working fine (using a string). Whats the thing they say about fixing something that is not broken.